# Gridview row height in android

Tags: android, gridview

I have a gridview, which gets loaded with textview and I am setting a background image for the text view. I want to vary the textviews height depending upon some logic, but to keep same height for gridview row. I tried this code but id didn't work. tv is my textview

```
    int Height = 150 + Integer.parseInt(PostCount);
    if(Height >= MaxHeight)
    {
     Height = MaxHeight;
    }
   tv.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(200, Height));
```

The rows overlap if I use the above above. Also I tried this without setting gridview params.

```
    int Height = 150 + Integer.parseInt(PostCount);
    if(Height >= MaxHeight)
    {
     Height = MaxHeight;
    }
    tv.setHeight(Height);
    tv.setWidth(200);
```

This just creates grid view with even width and height. I want constant width, but should be able to set the height according to the logic. Not sure where I am going wrong.I am not sure if I should go for table layout or grid layout. Help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help but maybe use LinearLayout as parent for each row and textview as the child.

In grid_item.xml

```
<LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="xdp"    <!-- where x is the max width for each row -->
     android:layout_height="ydp"   <!-- where y is the max height for each row -->

     <TextView
     // rest of the definition for Textview

     </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hi Thanks. It did help. Basically created a list item with textview and while loading it to the grid view, I used the AbsListView.LayoutParams and it worked.  `tv.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(Width,Height));`